# How would one interpret this simple chord progression? and what scales to use for improvisation?

Tags: scales, chord-theory, chord-progressions

So, I come across this progression fairly often:
e.g: G - A - C

I was wondering if this progression has a name since its used often in pop songs. 
I interpret it as V - VImajor - I.
Scales to use vary from Gminor pentatonic, to G lydian dominant - A mixolydian - C mixolydian. I am not that familiar with chord scale theory and was wondering how one would fit chord scale theory over this kind of progression?

Edit: after some comments I want to re-evaluate my previous statement about the interpretation of the progression. The progression drwas heavily to G, making it plausible that G is the I chord, making the progression I, IImajor, IV. Either case, the A is the odd one out. How does the A fit in this progression?

Comment: Do you have an example of a song that uses this progression? A more common progression would include Am, instead of A, and that would be in the key of A minor.

Comment: Can't really see how Gm pent notes fit well, or Mixolydian on either of the other two. Unless it has a blues tinge.

Comment: Hi Peter, I understand that Am is diatonic, but thats why I ask this question: how would one interpret thís progression. 
An example is the chorus from let love rule by Lenny Kravitz.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the analysis but its not contributing to an answer. If you want, you could play lydian dominant over each chord in the progression, but it would sound a bit odd.

Comment: What key feels like the tonal center? G?

Comment: Yes, strong pull to G, even from C.

Comment: @Tim, since the progression is not diatonic why not throw in more out notes?  G- pent will give it a bluesy tinge.

Comment: In fact the G blues scale has the maj 3rd of A and works great.  I'm trying G --> A --> C --> C-->  repeat.  Also, @TomvanHeusden, are you just playing power chords or full voicing?  The former allows for some key ambiguity.

Comment: @ggcg, triads, so no powerchords. G blues works great indeed, but what is the essence of this progression? How does the A fit in the progression?

Comment: by asking "fit in" are you asking for a functional harmony analysis?

Comment: @ michael curtis: Yes. With a relation to chord scale theory.

Comment: I didn't expect to 'contribute to an answer' That's why it's a comment!

Comment: It may not lend itself to analysis.

Comment: The sequence I II IV should be mentioned in the title of the question to find easily the link by related or similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.angelfire.com/fl4/moneychords/lydianprogression.html) names it the Pop-Rock Lydian II progression: I - II - IV - I.
Musicologist Allan W. Pollack attributed to The Beatles its first use in popular music (Eight Days a Week verse) and analyzed it as I - VofV - IV - I.

Comment: I have seen that description/analysis before, and I understand a `II` symbol can be used to show a major triad on the second scale degree, but `V/V` I don't really like. What dominant function is that chord fulfilling?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was what I was looking for. It also solidifies my initial lydian-feel with this progression. Thanks for the link and the explanation.

Comment: @TomvanHeusden, yeah, I guess I'm picky with _functional_ descriptions. When something is non-functional (like I believe this `II` is) then a functional `V/V` seems inappropriate. Of course that doesn't change the actual music, just chord labels.

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question, but the composer Debussy used lots of non functional triads and seventh chords. Trying to label such chords with Roman numeral analysis functions wouldn't make much sense. I think this is a similar situation but in the pop music genre

Comment: @michael curtis: thanks for the contribution. I agree. I have seen many attempts ramming songs into the nashvile numbering system that, to me, (though correct) don't make much sense. Giant steps, or Stella by Starlight for example.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I understand your rejection of the use of the V/V label in these cases. Alan Pollack did it all the time in his analysis of Beatles songs, though. For instance, talking about Yesterday: "The chord progression in which V-of-V is followed by IV, with its concomitant cross-relation and implied ethos of deferred gratification makes a somewhat surprising appearance here at the end of the verse." I think he was interested in highlighting this "deferred gratification" function. But I agree, use of Roman numerals in pop-rock is often loose.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - if V/V isn't followed by V, you're right, it can hardly be labelled as such. II sort of works, but often pop type music defies RNA. NNS works slightly better, but that's more for practical use than being an analytical tool.